# Load sharing using asynchronous motors

Tags: motor, generator, load, transmission

I am involved in the design of a system composed of:

- multiple asynchronous motors,
- each equipped with separate drive,
- all acting in parallel on a load,
- via a common rack and pinion transmission.

As the loads on motors are expected to be high, and the transmissions very stiff, we would like to implement a **load sharing** technique to make sure the motors share the loads sufficiently.

As we would like to avoid complex centralized systems, and possibly master/slaves architectures, we thought about something like [droop control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droop_speed_control).

Unfortunately, I could find very little about droop control on the internet for load sharing applied to asynchronous motors. What I mostly find are references to load sharing applied to synchronous generators. And most of them imply a master/slave architecture

I have then three questions:

1. Is droop control generally used for *distributed* load sharing using asynchronous motors?
2. If so, how is it generally implemented? How does it work?
3. Are there other distributed techniques generally recommended?

Comment: I've done (next to) nothing with induction motors.  But doesn't the amount of slip relate to the torque.  Can you measure the slip and use that to balance.  http://www.plantservices.com/articles/2002/48/?page=1

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, thanks. As you say, the slip in asynchronous motors already partly does the job I require. Usually though it's not enough to guarantee a smooth load sharing. For what I understood, droop control is a way to magnify artificially (and as much as required) the slip of the motors, without affecting their efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To answer your 3 quesions**

1. Droop can be used in many cases, including yours. But there are more elegant solutions to your problems. (Taking the pitfalls from the other answers in account
2. Droop is the opposite setting of a [proportional term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Proportional_term) (gain). On most (drive, engine, generator) systems the setting is in percentage. This percentage is the amount of speed (rpm, Hz) that would be dropped in case of 100% load. So instead of using a gain, we set a desired result.
3. See my use case below.

**Example for droop**

We have a motor we want to drive. It's nominal frequency is 60 Hz and its nominal power is 100 Kw. Because it's necessary in our plant, we set the droop to 2.5%. (Let's assume full load is reached at nominal speed.)

We give a *speed setpoint* of 60 Hz. The motor loads up to 100%. The actual speed you are going to end up with is 60-2.5%=60-1.5=58.5 Hz.

In parallel operation this would result in the following: if one of the coupled motors would pick up more power for whatever reason, its resulting speed would drop. At that point all the other motors would take it's load. But because they are drooped as well, they will drop along. So this can be tricky in an automated system where you need guaranteed speed.

This way all the power will be distributed near-equal. It is possible in some drive situations, where oscillating power shifts happen. (Like diesel generator plant). Increasing droop fixes this problem and is a cheap workaround to fix cheap regulators.

**Use case**

Last year I commissioned a [diesel-electric ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel-electric_transmission#Ships) where we used drives in a electric propulsion system, where we connected two 1000 kw drives in parallel on a single motor with a double set of windings. First we set them up in droop mode. But because we needed a guaranteed speed for our [DP systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_positioning) we changed the settings to master / follower.

Master / follower mode (answers your 3rd question) is timed over a fibre optic bus communication loop, and if the master fails, they all fail. This can be good or bad, depending on your application. But basically, only the master needs to handle external I/O like:

- Start / stop commands
- Safety stop system
- Speed input

So multiple drives act as a single unit and only one unit to interface with. Also the regulation is also very accurate, because speed set-point results truly in that speed (if not exceeding other limits, like torque). Whereas droop is dependent on the actual load. Also the load sharing is completely handled by the drives.

We used the [vacon nxp](http://www.vacon.com/products/AC-Drives/vacon-nxp-air-cooled/?source=products) drives. If you purchase them with the parallel running application, you can switch freely between droop and master / follower settings. Depending on your power demand: you can use stand alone units, common DC units or water cooled units. All from the same controller (NXP) range.

Comment: Since the time I wrote this question, I actually learned a lot more. I think your answer is clear and quite complete. I only miss what would be the more elegant solutions than droop. Did you mean master/slave?

Comment: Yes, I meant master/slave indeed

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use the analogy of a long conveyor belt which is driven by several AC motors along its length in order to distribute/share the overall power demand.

The problem of comparing your situation to the grid falls into two areas as I see it: -

1. There is always a master speed reference for electrical generation and THAT is the grid frequency - you wish to drive several asynchronous motors to move (say) a very long conveyor belt, each motor positioned every few hundred feet - the speed reference exists no-more because you might want the conveyor to stop or run slower or ramp-up or down in speed therefore there has to be a centralized control that tells each motor how much speed it is expected to produce - some motors will be more heavily laden than others (due to variations in belt stiffness or some other local mechanical difficulty) and speed control from a centralized point seems to be the only option.
2. Assuming that you can set a common speed demand to all the motors and their respective controllers, if one motor loses that communication it could easily turn into a generator and destroy your controller - you have to have a mechanism to counter this - on the grid this won't happen because the localized prime mover (steam turbine etc.) will start ramping down its fuel immediately and the generator will become a motor (off-load) for a brief instant and then resume acting as a generator.

In short I don't think droop control applies to your situation. I think you need a centralized demand system that each motor/system works with. I also think you need to be very careful about what happens when the demand signal is lost and the motor becomes a generator and back-feeds the motor variable speed drive.

Comment: Thanks. The analogy you make is clear and there will be, as you say, a common speed reference. But that won't make any of my motors a master. As a matter of fact, we don't want to complicate our system with a centralized (feed-back) architecture. The system should also be fail-safe in the sense that if one of the motors breaks, the other can just continue at the cost of a higher load. I believe a 'decentralized' droop control could do the job, but I've no experience with it...

Comment: I'd forget about the name droop control because it has little meaning in your scenario. Plain old common sense and good engineering is what is needed to make it work and if someone calls that x control or y control then fine!

Comment: Droop control is the most simple and common-senseful of the options I know, but I don't know much about other options, and I never used it before.
I can call it Mikey Mouse control, but how do you know what I'm speaking about? :)

Comment: What you call it or what I call it is of no consequence - an op-amp appears to be an op-amp until you look into the detail and some op-amps are as different as chalk and cheese - it's the detail that's important.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided more details on your application.  What is your transmission driving?  What are the horse power and speed requirements?  What are the dynamic load changes (What inertia response is required)?

Avoiding Complexity before you have fully defined your system requirements isn't advised.

how many motors are doing the load sharing?

You state that each motor has a separate motor and drive.  What is the horse power of each drive and what drive type and model that is being utilized.  Do the motors have speed feedback - such as encoders or is this an entirely open loop system?  How are the drives communicating to each other?

I am guessing that the system will utilize some type of open loop torque limit to share the load.  Based on one of your comments you desire to have the system continue to operated in the case of a motor failure.

With the limited information you provided, I am advising you to design a Global System gain to distribute the torque limit command to all the drives.  Divide this gain by the number of motors in the system Example 4 motors would be (1/4 =.25).  In the event of a failure the system can be manually of automatically rescaled Example (1/3 = .33).